# How can I apply clear both to wrap inside elemets in my container

Tags: css, css-float

How can I apply clear both to wrap inside elemets in my container

[JSFDDILE](http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/Am2vB/)

```
.container{
     background:blue;

}
.box{
    float:left;
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    margin:5px 5px;
    background:red;

}

.box:after{
    clear:both;
}
```

I want the boxes to be warpped by container!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Am2vB/3/)

```
.container:after{
    clear:both;
    content: " ";
    display: block;     
}
```

**OR**

Remove `float` and use `display: inline-block`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Am2vB/2/)

```
.box{    
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    margin:5px 5px;
    background:red;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! Nice! inline-block is so nice then! :-) Any special differences between float and inline-block appart form the fact that for in-line block you dont need to clear? BTW I have to wait 5 minutes to accept it as an answer :-)

Comment: @user3421904 Maybe this could help you about float and inline-block - http://joshnh.com/2012/02/07/why-you-should-use-inline-block-when-positioning-elements/